# yii set log path dynamically

Tags: php, logging, yii

friends i am using yii log to genrate log file for each user on the base of its id for its actions but when i am trying to set log file path dynamically then its not working please help me to find the way that how i can set dynamically log file path for logged in user.

```
$logger = new CFileLogRoute();
$logger->setLogPath("/app/protected/runtime/user-log/");
$logger->setLogFile("kumar-121.log");
$message='langusge changed from ';
Yii::log($message, 'CsvError', 'system.*');
```

buts it not working at all. please help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks friends but i got the answer what is did i firstly created my custom class and extand CFileLogRoute

then i just overwrite some parent file functions

class MyFileLogRoute  extends CFileLogRoute{

```
public function formatLogMessage($message,$level,$category,$time)
{
    return @date('Y/m/d H:i:s',$time)." - $message\n";
}

public function getLogFile()
{
    return 'user-'.(int)Yii::app()->user->id.'.log';
}

public function setLogFile($value)
{
    parent::setLogFile($value . (int)Yii::app()->user->id);
}
```

and this works perfect for me.

my first method i have created to remove level category from log file so it just simple log file

anyhow thanks